# WebExtention find statement

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am new to WebExtension programming. After I’ve completet some online tutorials, I decided to go on with an own little program which should simply add a borderframe to my tab when the corresponding page contains a specific word (browser.find.find(“word”)).
Permission to “find” is given. Unfortunately, it isn’t working. During debugging, the script stops at the "find" statement in the content script (Checked by console.log statements).

```
//Manifest.json:{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "webextension-example",
"version": "0.1",
"description": "An example.",

"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["borderify.js"]
    }
],
"permissions": [
    "notifications",
    "webNavigation",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "find"
]}
```

And the content_script:

```
function found(results) {
   if (results.count > 0) {
     console.log(`found at least one word (isn't triggered as well)`);
     browser.find.highlightResults();
     document.body.style.border = "50px solid red";
  }
}
console.log(`Checkpoint stil gets triggered`);
//>>> This is where I don't get any response
browser.find.find("and").then(found);
console.log(`Checkpoint doesn't get triggered`);
```

Comment: ... and where exactly does your code stop? At the first find, the second one, the `then`? I'd propose you to cut that piece of code into different lines, and see at which point exactly it stops working, and start debugging from there.

Comment: Hello Dominique, thanks for your response. It is stopping to respond exactly at this statement: browser.find.find("and").then(found). I further checked wether browser.find.highlightResults("and"); works. Unfortunately, I don't get a response as well...